# Cannot Install Expression Studio 3 on Windows 7 x86 in VMWare 6.5

Tags: windows, vmware, microsoft-expression

Cant seem to find help with this problem. Expression Blend 3 setup dialog is not displaying correctly (one button, missing background etc) which prevents me from installing it. I have tried setting various levels of compatibiliy and running as administrator but no luck. Anyone else have any luck installing Expression Blend in a VM?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - solution is to turn off the hardware acceration in the VMWare Graphic Driver (just as you do it a normal graphic driver).

Answer (score 0):

To adjust hardware acceleration in Windows 7 you'll go to:  Control Panel-Appearance and Personalization->Display-Screen Resolution.  Click advanced settings, then the trouble shoot tab.  Hit the button and then in the troubleshooter dialogue you'll be able to adjust the setting.